# SSH : How to add "2 Hours" to " targetHour=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%k` " and write to the "settings.xml" each time the script is started?

Tags: date, ssh, cron

For the past 2 weeks, about 3 to 7 hrs a day, I have been trying to get this script to write the correct date to the "settings.xml" file. I searched the internet everyday to try and find examples but no luck.

I am trying to make a demo site and found this script that I am trying to understand how it works. I went though each step to see if each step worked. So far 97% of the full script works but I don't understand why this part of the script is not adding the "30 Minutes" each time this script starts.

So my question is:
How to make this part of the script below write to the "settings.xml" file and add the "30 Minutes" or "2 Hours" to the time the script started?

Thanks, Mark E.

====== This Script Here === SSH ==============================

```
# How often the demo site will be refreshed?  
# You must keep in sync the crontab refresh time and this one, eg 30 minutes refresh in crontab, 30 minutes here  
# this value will be used to calculate and update the module that display a countdown  
# nextrun=1 months 2 days 3 hours 4 minute 3 sec   

nextrun="30 Minute"  

packagedestination="/home/username/public_html/demosite/"  

# This create a new file that can be checked for creation time in a dedicated Joomla! module  
function updateJoomlaModule() {  
base="${packagedestination}flashxml/countdownfx"  
file="${base}/settings.placeholder.xml";  
targetfile="${base}/settings.xml";  
if [ -f "$file" ]  
then  
nextRun=`date --date "now +${nextrun}"`  
targetYear=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%Y`  
targetMonth=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%m`  
targetDay=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%e`  
targetHour=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%k`  
targetMinute=`date --date "now +${nextrun}" +%M`  
echo "Next update $nextRun Updating file at $file"  
sed -i "s/_targetYear/${targetYear}/g;s/_targetMonth/${targetMonth}/g;s/_targetDay/${targetDay}/g;s/_targetHour/${targetHour}/g;s/_targetMinute/${targetMinute}/g" $file  
echo "Move ${file} to ${targetfile}"  
cp ${file} ${targetfile}  

echo "<html><body></body></html>" > ${base}/index.html  
else  
echo "countdownfx module not detected!";  
fi  
}
```

Comment: I got it! I updated my code to this: targetfile="${base}/settings.xml"  cp ${file} ${targetfile}  if [ -f "$file" ] and it works!

Comment: I forgot to say => Thank You! || Right now, I am trying to use PHP because for some reason it is not writing the Hours in SSH. I am looking on this site for more info because I don't know what I am doing or why I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

The -i option on sed does an in place edit of your placeholder file. Instead you could do a sed '...code...' > setting.xml and leave your placeholder file intact. Then you r script will be repeatable.